SQL Injection safety in mito/sxql
I started playing with some hobby webdev project in Common Lisp.
For DB access I'm planning on using mito and sxql. I'm trying to find out if I need to do any additional stuff to protect myself from SQL injections, but I'm not able to find any resources on that. Unforuntately my CL and SQL knowledge is not that good to asses that.
In this answer there's mention that using mito:retrieve-by-sql with :binds allows to "write a raw sql query and bind values safely". I believe this example would be usage of prepared statements, but what about other ways to write queries like mito:retrieve-dao or mito:retrieve-by-sql with query built with sxql:select and other sxql helpers.
Are they also designed to be safe? Would appreciate to see how this is solved in the above libraries.

All the library functions that create the query themselves should be safe. SQL injection happens when you construct the SQL yourself by concatenating strings.

Shall we try together an SQL injection?
0) Creating a DB, a table and a row
(defun connect ()
  "Connect to the DB."
  (mito:connect-toplevel :sqlite3 :database-name "myapp.db"))

(connect)  ;; creates myapp.db on the current working directory

(mito:deftable user ()
  ((name :col-type (:varchar 64))
   (email :col-type (or (:varchar 128) :null))))

(mito:ensure-table-exists 'user)  ;; creates a table

(mito:create-dao 'user :name "me")  ;; creates a user

(mito:find-dao 'user)  ;; retrieves our user

Trying SQL injections in a Mito query
This SQL command drops and looses the user table:
$ sqlite3 myapp.db
sqlite> .tables
user
sqlite> drop table user ;
sqlite> .tables
<<nothing>>

Can we safely create a new row from a user-submitted value?
(mito:create-dao 'user :name "; drop table user;")
;; => #<USER {1007585063}>

(inspect *)
The object is a STANDARD-OBJECT of type USER.
0. CREATED-AT: @2024-10-15T17:18:32.148719+02:00
1. UPDATED-AT: @2024-10-15T17:18:32.148719+02:00
2. SYNCED: T
3. ID: 1
4. NAME: "; drop table user"
5. EMAIL: NIL
> q

A new user was created, with name "; drop table user;", the tabl was not dropped.
This suggests you can safely create objects from a web form input.
A stupid (and dangerous) move
Now imagine you feed a user input to mito:select-by-sql:
(mito.dao:select-by-sql 'user  "drop table user;")

this drops the table.

That makes sense I guess.  I was also looking for the answer from the point of view of implementation, as there are different levels of mitigation against SQL injection - some might be able to filter out simpler attacks like above, but might not protect against some more advanced stuff.
